# Using Big-O notation?

Tags: calculus

Is there a difference between $O(n) + O(b)$ and $O(n+b)$ for two variables $n$ and $b$?

Comment: You cannot directly add $O()$ notations. The big O notation describes two functions that asymptotically is the same. It's not a particular value

Answer (score 2):

When people write things involving arithmetic and big-O notation they are usually speaking loosely. $O(a)$ is a *set of functions*, so the addition isn’t immediately meaningful. It seems probable the authors intend for $O(n+b)$ and $O(n)+O(b)$ to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In general the big Landau "O" is used to describe that two functions asymptotically behave identically, i.e.
$$ f(x) = O(g(x)) \; :\Leftrightarrow \; \lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1 $$
Is this how you have defined it?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x=O(x)$$

$$g(x)=-x=O(x)$$

$$h(x)=f(x)+g(x)=0=O(0)\neq O(x)$$

These hold from the definition of $O$